Laravel Impersonate User
I am trying to implement a impersonate feature into my Laravel 11 app without using any package. But it redirects back to login page.
Below is my middleware handle
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{        
    $impersonateId = 0;
    $impersonatorId = Auth::id();
    Log::info('middleware call');
    
    if(!$request->user()){
        Log::info('Request '.$request);
        return $next($request);
    }

    if($request->ajax()){
        $impersonateId = $request->session()->get('X-IMPERSONATE-USER-ID');
    }else{                     
        $impersonateId = $request->session()->get('impersonate-user-id');
    }
    Log::info('Impersonate user id is: '.$impersonateId);
    if($impersonateId != 0){
        $user = User::findOrFail($impersonateId);
        if($user){
            Log::info('Retrieved user'.$user);
            Auth::loginUsingId($impersonateId);
            Log::info('New user '. Auth::id());
        }
        
    }        
    
    return $next($request);
}

My web.php routings are like below
Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        //return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
        return Inertia::location('nova');
    })->name('dashboard');
    

     Route::get('/new-transfer', function(){
    return Inertia::render('LoyaltyPartnerSelection');
})->name('newtransfer');

     Route::any('/user-proxy/enter/{id}', function ($id) {    
    request()->session()->put('impersonate-user-id', $id);
    return redirect('/new-transfer');
})->middleware(Impersonate::class);

});

When I run this app it logs the impersonate user because it outputs the 'Retrieved user' and 'New user' with the correct user data in the middleware.
But when it does not route to 'new-transfer'. Instead it goes back to login page.
I am unable to figure out the issue. Looking for some help on this.
Thanks

This works if I put  Route::get('/new-transfer' out of the middleware group.

What happens if you replace Auth::loginUsingId($impersonateId); with Auth::login($user);? Or if you add the remember parameter: Auth::loginUsingId($impersonateId, $remember = true);

@Tony It didn't work. I tried. Still the same result

you ever get this working? https://github.com/thorst/laravel-jetstream-impersonate?tab=readme-ov-file Im close but if the impersonator and impersonated passwords arent the same it doesnt work
